# How to make a Discord bot activate itself?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, sudo

Sorry for the weird phrasing, I wasn't too sure on how to describe my issue but I will try my best. I am trying to make a sudo command in my discord bot For example, I am trying to make it so I can activate my #clear command. However, my bot simply writes #clear, and the command does not work. Is there a way I can make the bot use #clear? Sorry for the weird phrasing, I can try rewrite if this is unreadable.

```
@commands.command()
async def sudo(self, ctx, *, substance):
    """Get the bot to say something for you."""
    await ctx.send(f"{substance}")
```

Answer (score 2):

(I misunderstood your question the first time around.)

The documentation for [`self_bot`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.self_bot) states the following:

> If True, the bot will only listen to commands invoked by itself rather than ignoring itself. If False (the default) then the bot will ignore itself. This cannot be changed once initialised.

Meaning that this is the only "easy" way to make a bot listen to itself. As you can see, though, this makes it so that it doesn't listen to normal users anymore, so this is not what you want to do (as then you can't use your bot anymore).

One thing you can do is manually parse commands out of the message that was sent (in `on_message`), and look for a command that matches it. This then holds the complication that you don't have any `ctx` to pass into it, so it'll only really work for commands that don't use attributes of `ctx` that `message` doesn't have.

Comment: This did not seem to work for me for some reason. [This](https://imgur.com/IDMQ9KT) is what happened. (it did not respond)

Comment: I thought the bot itself would be included in this, but apparently not. I've edited my answer, but it's probably not something you'll like. Can I ask why you want your bot to respond to itself specifically instead of just calling the command yourself?

Comment: I'm working on a way to remotely use commands, from server A to take place in Server B, for example.

Answer (score -1):

In your code, you may be checking for who the command is sent by, a user or a bot. This may result in the bot ignoring itself and only listening to the user.

So I advise you to check if there is any statement that returns nothing (ignoring the command) if the author of the message is a bot. Edit: You can probably find it in the command handler (where you separate the args and the command).